# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

When I Want to post my Form in Asp.net.Mvc I get this Problem How can i fix that

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'FormValidation.Models.Entity.Personel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FormValidation.Models.Entity.Personel]'.

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
           

           
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(Personel personel)
        {

            return View(personel);
        }
```

## form index

```
@model FormValidation.Models.Entity.Personel
<form method="post" asp-action="Post" asp-controller="Home">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Name" />

            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Surname">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your surname" asp-for="Surname" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="City">City select</label>
                <select class="form-control" asp-for="City">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Age" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Age">Age</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Age" asp-for="Age" />

            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Adress">Adres</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" asp-for="Adress">Adres</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

**Post index**

```
@model IEnumerable<FormValidation.Models.Entity.Personel>
   

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p>@item.Name</p>
    <p>@item.Surname</p>
    <p>@item.Age</p>
    <p>@item.City</p>
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just as the error indicates,you passed the single personel model to render the view  with `return View(personel);`

However,the View requires `IEnumerable<Personel>`

If you just want to show the details of the model you just created ,modify your view :

```
@model FormValidation.Models.Entity.Personel
.......
    <p>@Model.Name</p>
    <p>@Model.Surname</p>
    <p>@Model.Age</p>
    <p>@Model.City</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it worked but I wonder why foreach loop  doesnt work

Comment: because you just  passed the single personel model to ViewDataDictionary,if you want to keep the codes in your view,you have to pass the arguement type of IEnumerable<Personel> or List<Personel> like:  var personellist=new List<Personel>(){...... } ,  return View(personellist)

Comment: thank you for your answers you answered all my questions